# what is the alternate to specify float in json data?

Tags: java, json, floating-point

I need to specify variable having floating values in my JSON file. But it does not recognize float values (e.g. **20.4444f, 0.5f** etc.), it seems. So I was wondering what could be the alternate to it in order to get float value assigned to variable in JSON?

Also, I will be using JSON file to set up lots of numeric parameter (of type string, float, double) in java.

1. Which will be appropriate java JSON API to use when one has to deal more with numeric data? Would really appreciate your inputs.
2. As far as I know Json Java APIs does not support reading of floating values from json file. is that right ?
3. I can think of one rough solution i.e. specifying value as double, reading it as Double and then converting it to float before actually using it. But I am afraid that converting double to float may not give me the exact value that I would have specified (as float if possible) in my json file. Your inputs please !

Comment: Define 'does not recognize'. Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @EJP To clarify, I can not write 20.4444f in my json file as Json does not treat float any differently.

Comment: Define 'can not write'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Don't add `f` after the float.

Answer (score 2):

> But I am afraid that converting double to float may not give me the exact value that I would have specified (as float if possible) in my json file. Your inputs please !

This is fine: the `float` -> `double` -> `float` roundtrip conversion is guaranteed to be exact by the IEEE754 format used by Java (the only exception is NaN values, which may not preserve payload bit patterns, but these won't be an issue as they're not supported by JSON anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Check the data-types present in java script :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm

whether it's int,float or double , all of these comes into same category of **Number** . 
For example, if you want to convert array of doubles into json string :

```
public class JsonPrimitiveArrays {        
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    double[] d = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0};
    jsonObject.put("doubles",d);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);            
}        
}
```

It will simply giving the output as :

> {"doubles":[1,2,3]}

All numbers are floats in Javascript. So, 1.0 and 1 are the same in JS. There is no differenciation of int, float and double.

Since JSON is going to end up as a JS object, there is no use in adding an extra '.0' since '1' represents a float as well. I guess this is done to save a few bytes in the string that is passed around.

So, you will get a float in JS, and if you parse it back to Java, you should get a double. Try it.

Adding one more example :

1.Write a DTO class :

```
package com.multithreading.concurrency;

public class Identidade {

  private int numero;
  private int numeroFinal;
  private float id;

  public Identidade(int numero, int numeroFinal, float id) {
   this.numero = numero;
   this.numeroFinal = numeroFinal;
   this.id = id;
   }

   // getters and setters
 }
```

2.Then write a parent bean, which will contain the above DTO reference :

```
public class ParentIdentidade { 

 @JsonProperty("Identidade")
 private List<Identidade> identidade;
 // getters and setters
}
```

Now, test it via below code :

```
public class TestIdentidade {

public static void main(String[] args) {        

    List<Identidade> idenList = new ArrayList<Identidade>();
    idenList.add(new Identidade(1704, 1804, 28.0f));
    idenList.add(new Identidade(1806, 1905, 28.3f));
    idenList.add(new Identidade(1705, 1706, 29f));
    idenList.add(new Identidade(1707, 1807, 30.38f));

    ParentIdentidade parentIden = new ParentIdentidade();
    parentIden.setIdentidade(idenList);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(parentIden);
        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the output as :

> {"Identidade":[{"numero":1704,"numeroFinal":1804,"id":28.0},{"numero":1806,"numeroFinal":1905,"id":28.3},{"numero":1705,"numeroFinal":1706,"id":29.0},{"numero":1707,"numeroFinal":1807,"id":30.38}]}

Comment: so if I want to assign value 20.4444f to the variable, I can simply write 20.4444 and then I read that value thru json API, I will get 20.4444. Is that u mean to Say ?

Comment: yes, you got it correct.

Comment: but the point is I have to have float format value in order to be able to use it further in my program. :-( and if I convert it back to float value, I may not get the float value which I exactly want and cosequently I get wrong result at the end ! (as specified in point 3. of question itself)