# In NodeJS, how to encode a 32 bits float number from a Buffer to a (json) string preserving original precision?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ieee-754

The input is a buffer containing single precision float numbers (32 bits, little endian).

What I want to produce is a JSON string containing those numbers, preserving the exact same values without precision change.

The problem is: as soon as the value is stored in a JS `number`, it is converted to 64bits, introducing precision changes.

For example:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from("cdcccc3d", "hex"); // cdcccc3d is 0.1 in 32 bits float LE
console.log(buffer.readFloatLE(0)); // 0.10000000149011612 => bad
```

How to get this value as a string preserving the original precision with no conversion? Here: `"0.1"`.

Bonus point if I manage to produce a JSON string containing the number with original precision: `{ "value": 0.1 }`.

Comment: 0.1 is not representable as an IEEE-754 float number, neither in 32 nor in 64 bits. Is the extra precision that allows you to see this fact causing any problems (apart from looking ugly, that is)?

Comment: Oh sorry my example is bad then, I used this site that told me it was exactly 0.1 https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ Yes this is a strong requirement that we keep the exact same precision, after being decoded the numbers are used by sensitive mathematical algorithms

Comment: You're not _losing_ any precision by the conversion from 32 to 64 bits. Any 32-bits float [can be perfectly represented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46386854/14637) as a 64-bits float. Whether that 64-bits float will still be exactly the same after conversion to string and back, I'm not sure, but in any case the difference will be so small that it vanishes if you then convert it back to a 32-bits float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little-endian bytes cd cc cc 3d are, in big-endian order, 3d cc cc cd, or the bits 0011 1101 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101.

In the IEEE-754 binary32 encoding, 0 is the sign bit, 011 1101 1 are the exponent field bits, and 100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101 are the significand field bits.

A 0 sign bit means positive.

The exponent field bits 011 1101 1 are 123 as raw binary. Exponents are encoded with a bias of 127, so the represented exponent is 123−127 = −4.

Since the exponent field is not zero (or all ones, which is used for infinities and NaNs), a 1 is prefixed to the significand field bits, forming 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101. As raw binary, this is 13,421,773. Significands are encoded with a scale of 2<sup>23</sup>, so the represented significand is 13,421,773/2<sup>23</sup>.

Combining the sign, exponent, and significand, the represented value is +2<sup>−4</sup>•13,421,773/2<sup>23</sup> = 0.100000001490116119384765625. This is the exact value represented, with no error. So you can see that the numeral produced for it, “0.10000000149011612” is accurate, as far as it goes.

Comment: oh thank you, that means I had wrong ideas about IEEE-754